# Grouping With aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Currently I'm using aggregation in MongoDB. There is a field with province and religion in my collections. I'm doing this

```
const data = await submit.aggregate([
    { "$group": { _id: { province: "$province" ,religion:"$religion"}, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
  ])
```

My output Looks like this:

```
[
  { _id: { religion: 'a', province: 'aa' }, count: 1 },
  { _id: { religion: b, province: 'bb' }, count: 2 },
  { _id: { religion: 'c', province: 'bb'}, count: 2 },
  { _id: { religion: 'd', province: 'cc' }, count: 1 } 
]
```

Expect Output:

```
[
  { _id: { religion: 'a ' }, count: 1 },
  { _id: { religion: 'a' }, count: 1 },
  { _id: { religion: null }, count: 6 },
  { _id: { religion: 'c' }, count: 1 },
  { _id: { religion: 'd' }, count: 2 },
  { _id: { religion: 'e' }, count: 6 },
  { _id: { religion: 'f' }, count: 15 },
  { _id: { religion: 'g' }, count: 2 },
 
 
] [
  { _id: { province: 'aa' }, count: 19 },
  { _id: { province: 'bb' }, count: 2 },
  { _id: { province: 'cc' }, count: 21 },
  
]
```

Comment: Share sample docs. Your expected o/p is invalid json. There should be a key.

Comment: Key is religion and province

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seek 2 different `$group` at the same time -- this is exactly what `$facet` is for.  Think of `$facet` like "multi-group."  Given an input set similar to the following:

```js
    { religion: 'a', province: 'aa' },
    { religion: 'b', province: 'aa' },
    { religion: 'c', province: 'aa' },
    { religion: 'c', province: 'bb' },
    { religion: 'd', province: 'bb' },
    { religion: 'e', province: 'cc' },      
    { religion: 'f', province: 'aa' },
    { religion: 'f', province: 'aa' },
    { religion: 'f', province: 'aa' },
    { religion: 'f', province: 'cc' }
```

Then this pipeline:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$facet: {
        "by_religion": [
            {$group: {_id: '$religion', N:{$sum:1}}}
        ],
        "by_province": [
            {$group: {_id: '$province', N:{$sum:1}}}
        ],
    }}  
]);
```

yields this output:

```js
{
    "by_religion" : [
        {
            "_id" : "b",
            "N" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "e",
            "N" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "d",
            "N" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "a",
            "N" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "f",
            "N" : 4
        },
        {
            "_id" : "c",
            "N" : 2
        }
    ],
    "by_province" : [
        {
            "_id" : "bb",
            "N" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : "cc",
            "N" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : "aa",
            "N" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

The OP seeks to further refine the output by doing some data-as-LVAL workup and although this is in general considered a poor design practice, it has certain useful applications.  Add this stage after `$facet`:

```js
    ,{$project: {
        // Reading this from insider-out:                                             
        // We use $map to turn the array of objects:                                  
        //   [ {_id:'d',N:1},{_id:'f',N:4}, ... ]                                     
        // into an array of K-v pairs (array of array):                               
        //   [ ['d',1] , ['f',4] , ...  ]                                             
        // That sets us up for $arrayToObject which will take                         
        // that array of arrays and turn it into an object:                           
        //   {'d':1, 'f':4, ... } 
        // The target field name is the same as the input so
        // we are simply overwriting the field.        
        "by_religion": {$arrayToObject: {$map: {
            input: '$by_religion',
                in: [ '$$this._id', '$$this.N' ]
            }}
        },
        "by_province": {$arrayToObject: {$map: {
            input: '$by_province',
                in: [ '$$this._id', '$$this.N' ]
            }}
        }
    }}
```

to yield:

```js
{
    "by_religion" : {
        "d" : 1,
        "b" : 1,
        "c" : 2,
        "f" : 4,
        "a" : 1,
        "e" : 1
    },
    "by_province" : {
        "bb" : 2,
        "cc" : 2,
        "aa" : 6
    }
}
```

A variation on the lval/rval workup uses this `$project` instead of the one immediately above:

```js
    ,{$project: {
          "by_religion": {$map: {
              input: '$by_religion',
              in: {$arrayToObject: [ [{k:'$$this._id',v:'$$this.N'}] ]}
          }},
          "by_province": {$map: {
              input: '$by_province',
              in: {$arrayToObject: [ [{k:'$$this._id',v:'$$this.N'}] ]}
          }},
    }}
```

which yields an array:

```js
{
    "by_religion" : [
        {"b" : 1},
        {"c" : 2},
        {"a" : 1},
        {"f" : 4},
        {"d" : 1},
        {"e" : 1}
    ],
    "by_province" : [
        {"cc" : 2},
        {"aa" : 6},
        {"bb" : 2}
    ]
}
```

Comment: What if I just want to get output like this:

"by_religion" : [
        {
           
            "b" : 1
        },
{
           
            "d" : 2
        },
]

i.e, b and d is the name of religion and 1 and 2 is the count

Comment: If you really want the label `by_religion` then simply remove the second `$group` (by_province) in the `$facet` above.   To simplify it further, for a single grouping, just do `db.foo.aggregate([ {$group: {_id: '$religion', N:{$sum:1}}} ])`

Comment: What if I want to show my output like this:
`[
 {
 "by_religion": [
 {
"hello": 63
},
{
"hey": 9
}
],
"by_province": [
{
"abcdef": 6
},
{
"ghij": 1
}]}]`

Comment: That is a poor data design practice.   Field names should be things like "count", "region", etc. and the values things like "hey" and "hello" and 9.   Making "hello" a field name is perhaps convenient for ease of display purposes but it clobbers the meaning of the key:value pair.   I will update the answer, however, to show it.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72403502/having-trouble-in-nested-array-of-abjects]. Check this out, This is what I want to do.