# Having trouble in nested array of abjects

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I've used Mongodb aggregation, $facet as I wanted to count every value of "reli" and "prov" from the collection.

This is my code to get results from db.

```
const keyy = await db.aggregate([
 $facet: { "reli": [
  { $group: { _id: '$reli', count: { $sum: 1 } } } ],
"prov": [
 { $group: { _id: '$prov', count: { $sum: 1 } } }
            ],
])
```

Output Looks like this:

```
 [
    {
            "reli": [
                        {
                            "_id": "abcdef",
                            "count": 6
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "ghij",
                            "count": 1
                        },
                    ],
    
            "prov": [
                    {
                        "_id": "hello",
                        "count": 63
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "hey",
                        "count": 9
                    },
                   ]
     
    
    }
    ]
```

But I want That my Expected output is :

```
 [
    {
            "reli":[
              {abcdef: 6},
              {ghij: 1}
                 ],
    
           "prov":[
              {"hello": 63},
              {"hey": 9}
                 ]
            
    }  
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate using `$map` and generate the new array with the values you want using `$arrayToObject` like this:

This query simply overwrite values `reli` and `prov` with the result of the map. That result is an array compound by objects where the key `k` is the `_id` value and the value `v` is the `count` value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "reli": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$reli",
          "in": {
            "$arrayToObject": [
              [
                {
                  k: "$$this._id",
                  v: "$$this.count"
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "prov": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$prov",
          "in": {
            "$arrayToObject": [
              [
                {
                  k: "$$this._id",
                  v: "$$this.count"
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d3l0-0Wv3XM)

Comment: **MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: input to $map must be an array not string** while using this code

Comment: Can you share the data with you are executing the query please?

Comment: The example is with the result of the `$group`, so you have to append the `$project` stage from my query into your query.

Comment: I've posted me query code above.

Comment: Using the output you provide can't be that issue because `reli` and `prov` are arrays, not strings... are you using `$` into the `input` (i.e. `$reli` and `$prov`)? Without the `$` mongo gets it as string.

Comment: Yes I'm using $reli and $prov, into input. Used same code you posted above.

Comment: I ran into this "$map needs array not string" problem earlier today.   There was something about wrapping an expression with `[ ]` to make it an array of one was getting overridden by the javascript to-string syntax of `[ ]`.   But now I cannot reproduce it!   I fiddled around with *something* and then it worked.

Comment: Can you share in a [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) the data and the solution?

Comment: Embarrassing!  It is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72366076/grouping-with-aggregation-in-mongodb/72366911#72366911   and I just realized the OP did a no-no and posted the same question twice.

Comment: @J.F.   Found it!  This was the quick code: `{$arrayToObject:['$$this._id','$$this.N']}`  It fails with `Expression $arrayToObject takes exactly 1 arguments. 2 were passed in.`  OK.  Then wrapping it with `[ ]` i.e. `{$arrayToObject:[['$$this._id','$$this.N']]}` yields `Unrecognised input type format for $arrayToObject: string`.   What *does* work is `{$arrayToObject: [ [ {k:'$$this._id',v:'$$this.N'} ] ]}`